# Does anyone know how to fix random green lines appearing on PsychoPy stimuli?

Tags: python, pyglet, psychopy

I've just started using `PsychoPy` and I've tried to flip text and a grating, both of which appear broken up with green lines.
Anyone know how to fix this?

I'm using PyCharm with Python 3.8 and I get these error messages, not sure if related:

```
C:\Users\USERID\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\codecs\wmf.py:838: UserWarning: [WinError -2147417850] Cannot change thread mode after it is set
  warnings.warn(str(err))
C:\Users\USERID\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyglet\image\codecs\wic.py:292: UserWarning: [WinError -2147417850] Cannot change thread mode after it is set
  warnings.warn(str(err))
```

Here is the code and image for the grating:

```
    import psychopy.visual
    import psychopy.event
    
    
    win = psychopy.visual.Window(
        size=[400,400],
        fullscr=False,
        units="pix")
    
    grating = psychopy.visual.GratingStim(
        win = win,
        units="pix",
        size=[150,150])
    
    grating.draw()
    win.flip()
    psychopy.event.waitKeys()
    win.close()
```

[image: grating_image]

EDIT: I rolled back pyglet to version 1.4.10 and the error messages disappear but the green lines remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution:

Try to add the argument multiSample and numSamples when you create your window, as in the example below:

```
w = visual.Window([wstim, hstim], color = [0, 0, 0], units = "pix", fullscr=False, multiSample=True, numSamples = 16)
```

In my script this worked fine.

Comment: In my projevt the actual window creation is hidden in the library, that i use, how do i use theese arguments?
The only line about the window in my code is:
animation.windowShape = (800, 800)
I used this lib:
https://github.com/morpho-matters/morpholib
To create a geometrical animation of a growing kite-shape.

Comment: Now i found a typo (projevt must be project) in my comment above but cannot edit it any more, can some one from the admins please fix that for me and delete this second comment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue but found that this is only the case on my computer. When I use the exact same code on a different computer, everything appears normal.

Comment: Yes, this is the same with me. I've spoken to Jon (creator of PsychoPy) and he isn't sure why this is happening.
What computer are you using? Mine is Dell XPS 15 9500

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which in my case seemed relate to the window size. It occured with vis.Window(size=[1400,800]) but changing this to vis.Window(size=[1920,1080]) solved it.